# Can git replace modular code design to some extent?

Tags: git, modularity

One of the reasons for a high degree of modular design is to allow different programmers to work on different aspects of the software. Another is re-usability.

For code where re-usability is redundant, e.g. when we have only one use of a particular module, to what extent might git branches be employed instead of modular code to facilitate collaboration?

Answer (score 1):

> ... What extent might git branches be employed instead of modular code to facilitate collaboration

This is exactly the concept using branches - develop new code and fix bugs without working on the current branch.

This is the right way to work and you understood it correctly.

---

## ***`git branch`***

> **A branch represents an independent line of development.**
>
> Branches serve as an abstraction for the edit/stage/commit process discussed in Git Basics, the first module of this series. You can think of them as a way to request a brand new working directory, staging area, and project history.
>
> New commits are recorded in the history for the current branch, **which results in a fork** in the history of the project.

---

> **In Git, branches are a part of your everyday development process.**
>
> When you want to **add a new feature** or **fix a bug** —no matter how big or how small—you spawn a new branch to encapsulate your changes.
>
> This makes sure that unstable code is never committed to the main code base, and it gives you the chance to clean up your feature’s history before merging it into the main branch.